# How to add a delay between each request in Tweepy StreamListener?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy and I don't find any option to add a delay between each request to make sure I'm not getting banned from Twitter APIs. I think 1 request each 5 seconds should be fine. How can I do this using StreamListener?

Comment: I think `time.sleep(5)` could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. You can never get banned from the Streaming API :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set timeout.

```
Stream(..., timeout=36000000)
```

You should also enable stall warnings in your `streamer.filter()` to see if Twitter is disconnecting yo or no `(stall_warnings=False)`.